# C# Program connected to a phpmyadmin database doesn't connect on network

Tags: c#, mysql, server, phpmyadmin

I made a c# program to keep track on inventory, this invetory is connected to a phpmyAdmin (MySQL) database. The program works fine in my PC (localhost) but when I try to use the program in another pc on the same network it says "Unable to connecto to any specific MySQL Host". I already switched the IP on the code and the port to the IPv4 and made a User on phpmyadmin with the IPv4 as well still doesn't connect... is there a way to fix this or I need to use another program as a Database?